# How can I read in a variable/value which is a runtime parameter that is inside a constant list of hashes?

Tags: perl, error-handling, constants, subroutine, hash-of-hashes

I have tried putting the variables in the string but it reads as blank when I run the program. Here is an example of what I'm working with:

```
        use constant {
    #list will contain more errors

    ERROR_SW => {
    errorCode => 727,
    message => "Not able to ping switch $switch_ip in $timeout seconds",
    fatal => 1,
    web_page => 'http://www.errorsolution.com/727',
    }
};

sub error_post {
    my ($error) = @_;
    print($error->{message});   
}
    error_post(ERROR_SW);
```

I simply want to post the error with the variable values included in the string.

Comment: If you want the constant to be dynamic, use a function. Constants are, er, constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been explained, your `ERROR_SW` is a *constant*, and may not contain run-time variables

If you intended `$switch_ip` and `$timeout` to also be constant values then, because `use constant` is evaluated at compile time, you would also have to declare and define these two variables beforehand. Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my ($switch_ip, $timeout);

BEGIN {
    ($switch_ip, $timeout) = qw/ 127.0.0.1 30 /;
}

use constant {
    ERROR_SW => {
        errorCode => 727,
        message   => "Not able to ping switch $switch_ip in $timeout seconds",
        fatal     => 1,
        web_page  => 'http://www.errorsolution.com/727',
    }
};

sub error_post {
    my ($error) = @_;
    print( $error->{message} );
}

error_post(ERROR_SW);
```

---

However I think you meant the message to vary with the values of these variables, which is impossible with a constant. The usual way is to define an error message to have constant error message string that contain `printf` field specifiers. Like this, for instance

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use constant {
    ERROR_SW => {
        errorCode => 727,
        message   => "Not able to ping switch %s in %s seconds",
        fatal     => 1,
        web_page  => 'http://www.errorsolution.com/727',
    }
};

my ( $switch_ip, $timeout ) = qw/ 127.0.0.1 30 /;

sub error_post {
    my ($error) = @_;
    printf $error->{message}, $switch_ip, $timeout;
}

error_post(ERROR_SW);
```

#### output

```
Not able to ping switch 127.0.0.1 in 30 seconds
```

---

An alternative way that **choroba** hinted at [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35918285/how-can-i-read-in-a-variable-value-which-is-a-runtime-parameter-that-is-inside-a/35918907#comment59495811_35918285) is to make the value of the `message` field a *subroutine reference*. That can be executed at run time to incorporate the current values of the parameters. That solution looks like this

Note the additional parentheses at the end of `$error->{message}()` to call the reference to be *called* instead of *evaluated*

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my ($switch_ip, $timeout);

use constant {
    ERROR_SW => {
        errorCode => 727,
        message   => message   => sub { "Not able to ping switch $switch_ip in $timeout seconds"},
        fatal     => 1,
        web_page  => 'http://www.errorsolution.com/727',
    }
};

($switch_ip, $timeout) = qw/ 192.168.0.1 99 /;

sub error_post {
    my ($error) = @_;
    print( $error->{message}() );
}

error_post(ERROR_SW);
```

#### output

```
Not able to ping switch 192.168.0.1 in 99 seconds
```

Comment: yeah @Borodin. This more like what I'm trying to do. I am trying to make at general subroutine though. As it will be accepting more than the 2 named variables. Is this possible?

Comment: @PaulRussell: Hello my Irish neighbour! I'm afraid it's not clear what you want to do, and I think you should write it up with examples, probably as a new question but possibly as an amendment of this one if you can do it without making nonsense of the existing responses

Comment: Making the message a subroutine reference seems like the perfect solution at the minute, I couldn't think of any other solution. Thanks @Borodin