# I am trying to create a template for placeholders for Error messages in perl. Any suggestions?

Tags: perl, templates, hash, error-handling, template-engine

I have a solution for this currently but it may not be the most versatile code. I know there is a way to use templates with placeholders for variables instead of putting the actual runtime parameters into the error message. Apologies if what I'm asking is unclear. I don't have a whole lot of knowledge on how to use templates.

```
 use constant {
    #list will contain more errors

    ERROR_SW => {
    errorCode => 727,
    message => sub{"Not able to ping switch $switch_ip in $timeout seconds"},
    fatal => 1,
    web_page => 'http://www.errorsolution.com/727',
    }
};

sub error_post {
    my ($error) = @_;
    print($error->{message}());   
}
    error_post(ERROR_SW);
```

I am trying to design it so that I can use placeholders for $switch_ip and $timeout instead of having to declare the message as a subroutine reference.
Like below

```
 use constant {
    #list will contain more errors

    ERROR_SW => {
    errorCode => 727,
    message => "Not able to ping switch **{{switch_ip}}** in **{{timeout}}** seconds",
    fatal => 1,
    web_page => 'http://www.errorsolution.com/727',
    }
};

sub error_post {
    my ($error) = @_;
    print($error->{message});   
}
    error_post(ERROR_SW);
```

They also appear in code like so:

```
%%error%%
```

I'm not sure how to create the template which will handle the parameters.
Again Apologies for being vague or not explaining this well.

Comment: Not sure whether you real question is about good practises for Error handling or about templates. My answer assumes that you are really asking about error handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't immediately see what this approach buys you that isn't provided by the `printf` format I [explained before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35918907/622310), but 
I suggest you use the [`Text::Template`](http://metacpan.org/module/Text::Template) module to do it this way. It is less extensive than [`Template::Toolkit`](http://metacpan.org/module/Template::Toolkit) but perfectly adequate for your purposes

Here's what a program using `Text::Template` would look like. I hope it helps you

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Text::Template qw/ fill_in_string /;

use constant {
    ERROR_SW => {
        errorCode => 727,
        message   => 'Not able to ping switch {$switch_ip} in {$timeout} seconds',
        fatal    => 1,
        web_page => 'http://www.errorsolution.com/727',
    }
};

my $values = {
    switch_ip => '192.168.0.1',
    timeout   => 60,
};

sub error_post {
    my ($error) = @_;
    print( fill_in_string($error->{message}, hash => $values) );
}

error_post(ERROR_SW);
```

#### output

```
Not able to ping switch 192.168.0.1 in 60 seconds
```

Comment: How could I make this work if the `$values` are actual parameters that the values aren't known? (they are known at runtime)

Comment: @PaulRussell: Those values are already assigned at run time. You should have no problem using the code directly

Answer (score 0):

I would create a package for each error type in you project. Each error object should have the necessary attributes to describe the error and a as_string() method giving a human readable message.

These packages can be written using you normal Object oriented framework (e.g. Moose). With good old perl objects it could look like this:

```
package My::Error;

sub new {
    my ($class, %self) = @_;
    bless \%self, $class;
}

package My::Error::SW;
use parent 'My::Error';

sub as_string {
    my $self = shift;

    return sprintf "Not able to ping switch %s in %s seconds", $self->{switch_ip}, $self->{timeout};
}
```

There exists multiple frameworks for this on CPAN. One example is the Throwable modules which uses Moose.

Comment: The biggest problem with anything based on `Moose` is that, together with its dependencies, it is a *huge* bundle of code and can take many minutes to install